# Не удается подключить GitLab Runner

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-runner

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь разобраться с GitLab Runner
Не удается подключить Runner.

Сделано следущее:

- Скачал Runner для Win
- Установил его через Shell с правами администратора.
- вызвал команду register
- указал URL из Settings - CI/CD - Runner
- указал token всязтый оттда же.
- указал описание
- НЕ указывал теги
- указал Shell

После был закинул в корень репозитория .gitlab-ci.yml
(В корректности которого я не уверен, просто подрезал его из какой-то статьи)
Не уверен что вообще корректно указал последнюю строку. Цель - развернуть сборку на собственном сервере. Указал логин и IP сервера ( если конечно так правильно )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

также создал SSH и закинул приватный ключ в Virables

В конечном итоге в Настройках ранера у меня возле созданного ранера отображется воскрицальеный знак в треугольнике. Значит ранер не подключился.

Что я сдлеал не так ?

Comment: запустите раннер в консоли и смотрите что пишет при создании новой задачи. Когда всё отладите, запустите как раннер как сервис

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо. Сам Runner не был запущен. Странно, что не указано статьях о необходимости его запуска ручками. 
Правда пока все равно скрипт не проходит. На build застревает

Comment: в GitLab выводит информацию о всех задачах. Можно посмотреть как проходит процесс сборки и на чём он застопорился. И лучше пользоваться командой `npm ci` вместо `npm install`